# Program stops after while loop

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a small program that reads the input and sets an array size, fills in the array and adds the numbers. My problem is that while I don't get any errors the program stops after the while. Any pointers as to what I am doing wrong would be very appreciated.

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] numbers = new int[in.nextInt()];
        int sum = 0;
        System.out.println("\n" + "numbers: " + numbers.length);

        while (in.hasNextLine()) {

            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                numbers[i] = in.nextInt();
                // System.out.println(numbers[i]);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= numbers.length; i++) {
            sum += numbers[i];

        }
        System.out.println(sum);

    }

}
```

Comment: `i <= numbers.length` take `=` out

Comment: it can't "stop". perhaps it's still waiting for input from you.

Comment: By "stop" do you mean silently exits? throws an exception? ...

Comment: Since he claims not to get any errors ..;

Comment: It doesn't throw any exceptions but it keeps running. If I enter some other input nothing happens.

Comment: I removed the while loop and it is working now. Thank you to all who helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `while` loop is not needed

```
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                if(in.hasNextInt())
                numbers[i] = in.nextInt();
                // System.out.println(numbers[i]);
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

As the JavaDoc for [Scanner.hashNextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine()) states:

> Returns true if there is another line in the input of this scanner.
>     **This method may block while waiting for input.** The scanner does not
>     advance past any input.

So your while loop will never finish:

```
while (in.hasNextLine())
```

Just remove this loop, your for loop inside is already doing the right job.

PS: And as [jipr311](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34226356/2546444) stated fix your second for loop or you will face an [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html):

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    sum += numbers[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no use of while loop. Remove that.
And edit the for loop like

`for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)`

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = null;
        try{
            in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int[] numbers = new int[in.nextInt()];
            int sum = 0;
            System.out.println("\n" + "numbers: " + numbers.length);
            int count = 0;
            while (count < numbers.length) {
                numbers[count] = in.nextInt();
                count++;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                sum += numbers[i];

            }
            System.out.println(sum);
        }finally{
            if(null != in){
                in.close();
            }
        }

    }
```

There also was a resource leak in the program as scanner object was not closed. I have corrected it.